# make [2]: **** [Makefile:44: envi_slc_decode] Error 1, while installing gmtsar in fedora 32

Tags: installation, makefile, compiler-errors, fedora

This is my first question in stack overflow and hope I make it clear.

I am trying to install a program (gmtsar) in fedora 32. However, the compilation was not complete and two errors return at the end.

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo -i
cd /usr/local
git clone --branch 6.0 https://github.com/gmtsar/gmtsar GMTSAR
cd GMTSAR
autoconf
./configure --with-orbits-dir=/usr/local/orbits
make
make install
```

after `make` and  `mak install` the following errors return:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:44: envi_slc_decode] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/GMTSAR/preproc/ENVI_preproc/ENVI_SLC_decode'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/GMTSAR/preproc/ENVI_preproc'
make: *** [Makefile:37: preprocess] Error 2
```

I followed the same procedures in ubuntu 16.04 and the compilation was complete without errors.

Can anyone help me understand why I got these errors and how to fix them, please?

Comment: You  have not provided the most important output.  The errors you have provided or just make telling you "something failed when I tried to run `ld`" (which is the linker).  The actually interesting messages appear above this and tell you why the linker failed.  If I had to guess I'd say it couldn't find some libraries that were installed on your Ubuntu 16.04 but not on your fedora.  But the error messages will tell you.

Comment: @MadScientist, Thank you for your comment. The output of make is very long, I am not sure if it is OK to post the whole terminal output.

Comment: Well, almost always the important errors are the _first_ errors shown.  It's very rarely the case that the _last_ errors are so useful.  If they are they'll still be there once you've solved the first ones :).  But, they are often either because of the same problem, or even caused by the first ones.  So, post the first 5-10 lines of error output.  But as I said, likely the problem is a missing library so before posting the errors, you can try to understand what they mean and see if you need to install more libraries, etc.